# build specific icon from data

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I want to display a specific icon in different boxes using d3.
I have a data as an array of `[x0, y0, x1, y1, vx, vy]` where:

- x0, y0 is the first corner of a box,
- x1, y1 the second corner and
- vx, vy two parameters (velocity)

that will be used to generate a SVG path.

I am using:

```
var boxes = nodeSVGGroup.selectAll("rect").data(nodes).enter().append("rect");
```

to generate my boxes and this is working well

My problem comes when I want to create the SVG path (icon) and properly render it in each box (it needs to be generated, translated and rotated to fit the center of each box.

I am using a similar pattern i.e.

```
var selection = nodeSVGGroup.selectAll(".barb").data(nodes);

selection.enter()
  .append('g')
  .each(function(node, i) {
    var vx = node[4];
    var vy = node[5];

    var speed = Math.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy);
    var angle = Math.atan2(vx, vy);

    // generate a path based on speed. it looks like 
    // M2 L8 2 M0 0 L1 2 Z
    var path  = ...
    var scale = 0.5*(node[1]-node[0])/8;

    var g = d3.select(this).data([path,angle,scale]).enter().append('g');

    // still need to add following transforms
    //   translate(' + node[2] + ', ' + node[3] + ') 
    //   scale(' + scale + ') 
    //   rotate(' + angle + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + 0 + ')  
    //   translate(-8, -2)',

    g.append('path').attr('d', function(d){console.log(d); return d[0];})
                    .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke');
  })
  .attr('class', 'wind-arrow');
```

I get the error  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null(…)` which seems to be related to this line

```
    .each(function(node, i) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

The full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/galleon/k8t4n0s3/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear why are you trying to create an "enter" selection inside an `each`. I'm not sure if I understand your goals, but you can simply use `d3.select(this)` to append the path to each group:

```
d3.select(this).append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9x169eL1/

Comment: I think you have perfectly understood what I was willing to do. Thanks. Here is the final [version](https://jsfiddle.net/galleon/k8t4n0s3/9/)